# c# Reflection MakeGenericMethod multiple generic types in method definition

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following generic method

```
 public static T2 MapCollection<T1, T2, T3, T4>(T1 source) 
            where T1 : ICollection<T3> 
            where T2 : ICollection<T4>
        {
          ...
        }
```

The goal here is to call this method using reflection so I need to MakeGenericMethod...

I do this like this :

```
Type type1 = prop1.PropertyType;
Type type2 = prop2.PropertyType;
Type type3 = prop3.PropertyType;
Type type4 = prop4.PropertyType;

MethodInfo mi = typeof (DynamicMapper).GetMethod("MapCollection");

Type[] typeArgs = { type1, type2, type3, type4 };

mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeArgs);
```

Then, I try to invoke the method..

```
object[] parametersArray = new object[] { value }; // value is set earlier in the code (PropertyInfo.GetValue(...))
object foo = mi.Invoke(null, parametersArray);
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.
```

I think this has something to do with the fact the the Generic Method has 4 generics arguments and only one parameter...

What am my missing on this?

Comment: @xtnd8 Baral already uses the code in the answer, but it is not working. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Jashaszun if OP would use code from duplicate they would not ignore result of `MakeGenericMethod`.

Comment: Boy, is very simple....  mi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeArgs);  // :)

Comment: Call GetGenericMethodDeffinition first to get a method template without type parameters and on the resulted methodinfo call makegenericmethod